# Check Boxes in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am having checkboxes in my html and pagination has also been implemented.
when i select few of the check boxes in first page and go to the next page through pagination,It unselects the previous page's check box.
and when i click submit it gives me values of the current page's selected check boxes only.
How to retrieve all the selected check boxes in one go.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remember that HTTP is stateless. Anything a user does on one page is not remembered unless you explicitly remember it and replicate it. Make the Next button a submit button which goes to the next page, read the checkbox values out of the post data, and set them manually on the next page.

Answer (score 2):

I do an ajax request for every click someone does in [rboard](http://github.com/radar/rboard) when they're moderating topics. This is a way that you could go.